# Set date in datepicker using Selenium WebDriver and C#

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

I am using [Selenium WebDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/). I have `datepicker` on a web page, and I want to set a date into that control.

I am using `.SendKeys("12/31/2015")`, but it does not select that date on the screen. It shows 31/__/2015 only.

So how can I set datepicker's value?

***Note: `Datepicker` is `AjaxControlToolkit:CalendarExtender`***

Comment: You will have to pickup date using particular date Xpath. Open calendar , Get particular day xpath , Click on that...

Comment: Date will not be fixed. it may not belong to this month. So XPath of that will not be fixed. In this case Xpath may not work.

Comment: I know that but I don't think any other option available here. you can take xpath of any date you want. It can be of any month.

Comment: I tried this. What I did is, First Click on CalendarTextBox so calendar gets open, Then click on Date's Xpath but it gives me error of SeleniumNotVisibleException. But calender is open on page and I can see that date being shown there.

Comment: Awesome , Just put explicit wait or thread.sleep(20000) after open calendar and then put your date xpath code. Actually selenium need time to find date after open calendar so.

Comment: I tried this. but still it shows same error. SeleniumNotVisibleException (Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with). Any solution?

Comment: @Sagar this will help you out. Please go through this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51106612/how-to-automate-md2-datepicker-using-c-sharp-selenium/51106704#51106704

Comment: This is how to Automate the date picker using c# selenium https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51106612/how-to-automate-md2-datepicker-using-c-sharp-selenium/51106704#51106704

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the Datepicker is not your code you don't need to test it's functionality, so what I would do is write a JavaScript snippet that sets it to the required value, then execute that in the browser.

Comment: It worked for me. I registered javscript like below
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
                        js.ExecuteScript("$('#idofDate').click();"); 
it selects particular date.

Comment: (its = possessive, it's = "it is" or "it has". See for example <http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Its-and-It%27s>.)

Answer (score 2):

If yout are testing mobile browser and you need type on required date field to finish fill form, my solution works with any phone in any operational system.

```
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  js.executeScript("document.getElementById('id').value='1988-01-01'");
```

Comment: could you elebarate on the answer a little bit?  Why do you feel this is a good solution?

Comment: Hi Bruno! As a general rule, when answering a question that already has an excepted answer and has for some time, you generally have to really "bring it to the table" with your answer. This isn't to discourage contributing to old posts, but the bar is set with the green checkmark. So this isn't a terrible answer, but it doesn't hold up to the answer that already exists and is accepted. Make sense?

Comment: @ECiurleo If yout are testing mobile browser and you need type on required date field to finish fill form, my solution works with any phone in any operational system.
"corsiKa" I answering a question " I want to set a date" beacuse the acepted answer don't provide "code" to solve the problem.

Comment: add your comment details into your answer so everyone can see them.  Its perfectly acceptable to improve your answers based on comment feedback, in fact, its encouraged!

Comment: this is a beautiful solution, as it seems to cover any 3rd party date time picker controls as well so low level that it uses value to set any thing, I was unable to find against some particular 3rd party control and this worked like a charm